# Demodulation of amplitude data in python

Tags: digital-communications, python, demodulation

I'm trying to work out a way to demodulate series of amplitude data points in python.  The original data consisted of a total of 360 bits which is now contained in slightly under 720 samples (the signal starts with a clock run-in of "10101010").  My questions are:

- What methods in python would be appropriate to retrieve the original bits/bytes from this signal?
- How to handle bitrate detection noting the relatively tiny sample rate of just under 2 samples per bit?

As a scatter plot it looks like this:
[image: Scatter plot]

But as a line chart it's much more clear:

[image: linechart]

Sample data:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 59.0, 154.0, 104.0, 1.0, 74.0, 160.0, 89.0, 0.0, 85.0, 165.0, 78.0, 1.0, 103.0, 157.0, 60.0, 2.0, 111.0, 156.0, 46.0, 11.0, 130.0, 145.0, 33.0, 20.0, 133.0, 139.0, 23.0, 30.0, 145.0, 132.0, 15.0, 41.0, 150.0, 171.0, 163.0, 166.0, 165.0, 101.0, 8.0, 0.0, 2.0, 73.0, 166.0, 88.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 89.0, 158.0, 62.0, 5.0, 110.0, 156.0, 52.0, 3.0, 121.0, 149.0, 41.0, 3.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 25.0, 136.0, 133.0, 19.0, 30.0, 154.0, 121.0, 15.0, 41.0, 157.0, 110.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0, 98.0, 158.0, 53.0, 4.0, 114.0, 166.0, 165.0, 145.0, 41.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 38.0, 146.0, 124.0, 12.0, 47.0, 154.0, 164.0, 164.0, 167.0, 168.0, 97.0, 9.0, 72.0, 164.0, 82.0, 3.0, 82.0, 161.0, 73.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 135.0, 143.0, 22.0, 31.0, 144.0, 165.0, 167.0, 163.0, 167.0, 115.0, 10.0, 55.0, 158.0, 104.0, 0.0, 71.0, 158.0, 88.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 122.0, 150.0, 34.0, 20.0, 132.0, 172.0, 161.0, 170.0, 164.0, 165.0, 166.0, 121.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 54.0, 153.0, 174.0, 166.0, 164.0, 164.0, 93.0, 3.0, 80.0, 164.0, 79.0, 0.0, 93.0, 157.0, 69.0, 5.0, 110.0, 156.0, 57.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 22.0, 137.0, 165.0, 165.0, 137.0, 23.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 59.0, 154.0, 104.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 98.0, 154.0, 64.0, 0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 143.0, 131.0, 19.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 82.0, 156.0, 81.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 133.0, 137.0, 30.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 9.0, 52.0, 161.0, 91.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 12.0, 110.0, 149.0, 47.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 151.0, 105.0, 13.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 95.0, 161.0, 48.0, 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 31.0, 142.0, 131.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 86.0, 157.0, 80.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 22.0, 130.0, 139.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 68.0, 156.0, 94.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 10.0, 118.0, 149.0, 37.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 50.0, 152.0, 107.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 107.0, 153.0, 54.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 33.0, 143.0, 129.0, 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0, 154.0, 74.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 135.0, 135.0, 25.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 71.0, 158.0, 88.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 124.0, 143.0, 38.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 52.0, 154.0, 107.0, 6.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 156.0, 57.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 23.0, 149.0, 117.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 8.0, 81.0, 159.0, 69.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 26.0, 132.0, 130.0, 25.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0, 72.0, 159.0, 78.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19.0, 119.0, 149.0, 23.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 59.0, 154.0, 104.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 8.0, 109.0, 151.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 145.0, 121.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 93.0, 154.0, 67.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

Comment: do you have an indication of what the modulation method is?

Comment: It started it's life as binary data that was encoded into the vertical blanking of a video frame.  They're basically the equivalent of DC pulses encoded in the luma of the video pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have about two samples per symbol. If you mark the local maxima that becomes more obvious

[image]

The whole tail end (after 200 or so) is boring. It's just regular peaks with the same amplitude and spacing. So all the data seems to be in the early part. It appears to be a simple binary code, it's either one or zero.

I'm not sure if your sample clock is  phase locked to the sample clock, but it's easy enough to time slice it by hand.

However, there don't appear to be 360 bits in there. It's maybe 100 or so.

Comment: It's the "boring" part that highlights the challenge.  Each of those spikes appears to be a single bit.  But because of the resolution, they're between 15 and 16 samples apart.  There isn't enough resolution to just take every second sample, compare it to a threshold and call it a zero or one.  I was hoping there was some sort of method for interpolating it somehow and running through an algorithm to spit out the ones and zeros.

Comment: There is. You need to run a "PLL" to sync your sample clock to your symbol clock. You can also just manually count the number of symbols and divide by the number of samples, which gives you the symbol rate. Then resample, so that becomes an integer.